# Is it possible to profile a script run in WLST?

Tags: python, weblogic11g, wlst

Is it possible to profile a script run in wlst? I need to profile a python script that migrates data from an XML file to an LDAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am answering my own question! Yes it is possible to profile. The JVM arguements needed for JProfiler/any other profiler needs to be added to wlst.sh and it works.